# Ошибка при подключении к MySQL 8.0.15-a2

Tags: mysql, mysqli

У меня возникла проблема с MySQL я недавно ее поставил настроил и вот тут уже проблема с коннектором **Внимание Phpmyadmin работает** без проблем а коннект через плагин майнкрафта не работает ну и другие возможно тоже не работают

вывод ошибки:
С MySQL https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYlKu.png

С MariaDB работает

С psql работает

phpmyadmin https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdDLP.png

Кто знает причину возникновения ошибки пожалуйста напишите

Comment: Ну вроде как вменяемо пишут, что проблема с зоной времени. И даже пишут, как устранить - правильно настройте JDBC-драйвер.

Comment: JDBC в порядке это проблема с зоной времени но есть еще одна ошибка после исправления зоны времени java.sql.SQLException: Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) and (utf8_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='